# jquery mobile: Change textarea background after submit button has been pressed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-mobile, mobile, textarea

I want to change a text area that displays either "Login successful!" or "Login unsuccesful!" after the Login button of a HTML form has been pressed.  The text area should fade in when a the login button is pressed.

If the login was sucessful, 
the background of this textarea should changed to green with black fonts and display the message.

If unsuccesful, the textarea should be changed to red with white fonts and display the error message (with a error handler).

By default, this textarea is hidden.

Note that I will receive a callback from the server if the user/password was found or not, but this is going to be implemented later on. Therefore, I just want to send a random "true" or "false" when the login_submit button is clicked.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<div data-role="content">

<form method="POST" data-ajax="false">
<label for="login_username">Username:</label>
<input type="text" name="login_username" id="login_username"/><br>

<label for="login_password">Passwort:</label>
<input type="password" name="login_password" id="login_password"/><br>

<input type="submit" id="login_submit" value="Login" /><br>
<input type="reset" id="login_reset" value="Reset"><br>
</form>

 <textarea id="message" style="color: white; 
 background-color: grey; visibility: hidden"  readonly> Default </textarea>

</div>
```

This is my jquery mobile code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

$('#login_submit').click(function(){

     $('message').change(function(success) {

     //How do I receive a variable from the html code?
     //success should be random either true or false
     //success variable is a callback from the server, but is not implemented yet


      if(success == true) {

      //I don´t know what to write in here, it should fade in the text area, 
      //change the background to green with white font and 
      // display the message  "Successful login!"
      } 

      if(success == false) {
      //error handler, 
      //change the background to green with white font and 
      // display the error message (if possible), otherwise "Unsuccessful login!"
      }

 });

});
```

Could someone tell me what to add for the code?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/YL6Da/

I removed your style attribute in the code, and added classes based on a failed or successful login.

jQuery

```
if (success) {
     $("#message").fadeIn("slow").removeAttr("style").addClass("success").text("Successful!");
} else {
     $("#message").fadeIn("slow").removeAttr("style").addClass("error").text("Failed");
}
```

CSS

```
.success {
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}

.error {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot! I just deleted the whole style description from the <textarea> and put 3 new classes into my css: plainmsg, success and error with grey, green and red background respectively. Now I got the problem that after I clicked several times on Login, both success and error class are added to the textarea which results in displaying "Error login" with a green background. I tried to fix it with that code, but it doesnt work

Comment: `if(success)                                                           { $("#message").fadeIn("slow").addClass("success").text("Login successful!"); }                                                 else { $("#message").fadeIna("slow").addClass("error").text("Login not successful!"); } });`

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery .css() to modify the element CSS properties, as explained here: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

```
if(success == false) {
      $('#message').css("background-color","red");
      $('#message').css("color","white");
      $('#message').text('whatever text you want');
      $('#message').show();
}
else {
     $('#message').hide();
}
```